# Why is strftime being removed from php?

Tags: php

I searched the whole web, but was not able to find the reason *why* `strftime` is being removed from php. From my point of view it was the perfect function for easy access to custom date formats. The "alternative" `IntlDateFormatter::format()` feels so cumbersome.

Can anyone explain why `strftime` is no longer part of php?

Comment: If `strftime()` is not cumbersome for someone, they're possibly using it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It's because it has "better" methods, like `IntlDateFormatter::format`

As stated in [here](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/strftime-gmstrftime-deprecated)

> PHP offers locale-independent and locale-aware time formatting APIs that are better, feature-rich, and more intuitive. In PHP 8.1 and later, strftime and gmstrftime are deprecated, and using them emits a deprecation notice. These functions will be removed in PHP 9.0.

The problem is also stated there:

> strftime and gmstrftime functions format a Unix timestamp based on the current locale set using the setlocale function. gmstrftime function is similar to strftime, except that it returns the time in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

> setlocale function sets the locale setting to the PHP process, rather than the current working thread. This can result in sudden change in the locale if another thread calls setlocale function. This can be specially troublesome if PHP is used in a multi-threaded Server API (such as mod_php for PHP).

It also quotes [replacements](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/strftime-gmstrftime-deprecated#replacements):

> For locale-aware date/time formatting, use IntlDateFormatter::format (requires Intl extension).

> In a real-life and ideal use case, the IntlDateFormatter object is instantiated once based on the user's locale information, and the object instance can is used whenever necessary.

```
 setlocale(LC_TIME, "en_US");
 echo strftime('%x', time());
 $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('en_US', IntlDateFormatter::LONG, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
 echo $formatter->format(time());
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/strftime-gmstrftime-deprecated):

> strftime and gmstrftime functions format a Unix timestamp based on the
> current locale set using the setlocale function. gmstrftime function
> is similar to strftime, except that it returns the time in Greenwich
> Mean Time (GMT).
>
> setlocale function sets the locale setting to the PHP process, rather
> than the current working thread. This can result in sudden change in
> the locale if another thread calls setlocale function. This can be
> specially troublesome if PHP is used in a multi-threaded Server API
> (such as mod_php for PHP).
>
> PHP offers locale-independent and locale-aware time formatting APIs
> that are better, feature-rich, and more intuitive. In PHP 8.1 and
> later, strftime and gmstrftime are deprecated, and using them emits a
> deprecation notice. These functions will be removed in PHP 9.0.